# Searching by views

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, search-results

Searching is hard to completely understand using SharePoint 2013.

Is there a way to restrict search results to come from a certain view in document library?

It is possible to build a query?

I am thinking that I can restrict by `Tag` to make this happen, but I am not sure.

Is it possible to produce search results from a certain view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Try adding a search results webpart to you page, and edit the properties.

Then click on "change query". You can specify a tag there.

[image]

If you use SharePoint 2013 Enterprise you can also you the CSWP.

Also you can do much more via the advanced view (Switch to Advanced Mode):
[image]

Comment: Do I place name of the view in the Restrict on this tag field? Thanks, @Patrick

Comment: You can return items only from a specific path and also filter for metadata

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to have the view link to not appear as one of the search results?  I just want the documents to show in the results not the link to view.  Thanks, @Patrick.

Comment: Therefore you have to use your own display template. It is not that difficult. Try bing it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "Query a View". You can evaluate the view filter criteria and replicate the query in search. So if you want to filter on a Hashtag simply query the hashtag, like `#SharePoint`. If you are using other types of metadata you can query that too. The search engine is actually very controllable and predictable. If you are struggling I recommend the excellent book on the topic, Search Queries Explained. http://www.techmikael.com/2015/01/sharepoint-search-queries-explainedthe.html Mikael's blog is excellent as well.